# MSVC++ Compiler Error C2892?

Tags: visual-c++

```
int main() {
 struct local {
  template<class T>   // This line generates C2892 error.
  void f() {}
 };
}
```

Why I cannot use template member in local classes and structures? What causes such restrictions in Visual C++?

Answer (score 3):

C++03 14.5.2/2 "Member templates" says:

> A local class shall not have member templates

(same in C++98 and C++11). I don't know what the rationale is.

Comment: 11 years later and four standard revisions later, is this requirement relaxed yet?